# Javascript won't work when typed

Tags: javascript

So, I'm brand new to javascript. This code works when copy/pasted from W3. But when I type it, it won't work. Please, in your answers, act like I'm an idiot and explain things as if I know nothing about it. Seriously no sarcasm there. It'll help me out a ton. lol My whole page is short because I'm just fiddling, so I just pasted the entire thing below. I put stars next to the two parts that I'm referring to. I've been digging for hours and can't find a solution. Thank you guys in advance for being cool and helping a beginner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Java Testing</title>

    <style>
        h1
        {background-color:black;
        font-size:60;
        color:white;
        text-align:center;}

        p
        {text-align:center;
        color:black;}

    </style>


</head>

<body>

    <h1>I&#39m trying out some Java.</h1>

    <p>But I&#39m not entirely sure what I&#39m doing.</p>
*
<script>
document.write("<h1>This is a heading</h1>");
document.write("<p>This is a paragraph.</p>");
</script>
*

*
<script>
document.write(“<h1>This is a heading</h1>”);
document.write(“<p>This is a paragraph.</p>”);
</script>
*

    <p>
    <button>Try it</button>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The part you've typed -- is it the second one?

Comment: Looks like the problem occurs because of the quotes.

Comment: Did you notice that the quotes are different?

Comment: Note: Immediately after posting, I noticed in the string of script that I typed, "this" is highlighted in blue while the entire sentence is red in the version that I copy/pasted. Not sure what that means.

Comment: What do you mean 'when you type it'? Also, part of your problem may be the quotes in the second starred section of code. They're special characters and not correct `"`'s. Many browsers come with developer tools which have a 'console' and that will show you any JavaScript errors that may have occurred on your page. Start using this.

Comment: How cool! The SO-syntax-highlighting actually solves the problem xD

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. But why?

Comment: I guess you are referring to w3schools by "W3". I suggest you stop using their tutorials, because they are outdated and low quality. For example, `document.write` is not recommended to use (unless you really know what you are doing).

Comment: I advise you get a syntax highlighting editor e.g. Dreamweaver/Notepad++/Eclipse (If you want to go down the IDE route)

Comment: What program are you trying to write this in?  The way the quotes show up like that make me think you're using some rich text editor (like Word)

Comment: Oh yeah, also http://w3fools.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using smart quotes (like `“`), not normal quotes.

Use an IDE, or at least just a plain text editor like Notepad on Windows.

Also, Java is NOT JavaScript! They are two completely different languages.

Comment: This completely fixed it. I disabled smart quotes. Thank you guys so much. Let me know if there's something I should do to highlight this answer.

Comment: To be more specific, I was using TextEdit on Mac and there was an option in preferences to turn it off.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that link, Doorknob. I guess you can't tell you're being taught terribly until you've been taught well. Your link helped me find some tutorials that are just plain awesome and unbelievably clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the quotes in the second part. That may be an issue with your editor. Are you using any kind of Text Processor? That may be the issue. Javascript only supports single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`).